# Is there a smaller alternative to node:18-alpine docker image?

Tags: node.js, docker

Just the bare node:18-alpine is already 166MB.

I have removed extra useless packages there but only 12MB could be saved. There is not much room to improve there.

Is there some third-party docker image that is smaller?

Comment: "I have cut my part to only few 12MB so there is not much room to improve there."  What do you mean by this?

Comment: Multi stage build should help you.

Comment: @BertC Final docker image is only 12MB larger than the bare node:18-alpine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you could try is to use alpine only, this should be around 6mb; as

```
FROM alpine
```

However, `alpine` is just a lightweight Linux and there is no Node.js. So you will have to install it separately;

```
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm
```

you should get an image close to 60mb.

Comment: Thank you. It was more complicated than that but you pointed to the direction.

Comment: @tech-escape are you able to post your solution?